# Changing Flex-Basis on different screen size

Tags: html, css

I wonder why this doesn't work.

```css
#parent {
  display: flex !important;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100% !important;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}
.item{
 flex: 1 !important;
 flex-basis: calc(100% / 4);
 box-sizing: border-box ;
 border: solid 1px #000000;
 margin-bottom: 30px !important;
 max-width: 24%;
  height: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
/* start of medium tablet styles */
 .item{
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3) !important;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
/* start of phone styles */
 .item{
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 2) !important;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I wanted to change the `flex-basis` of the flex items on the mobile and tablet screen. Normally, the row items should be 4 and in the tablet, it should be 3 then on mobile it should be 2.

Comment: Would it be better to use css grid here and just use `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr` for example for 2 boxes per row, or `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;` for 4 per row.

Comment: @anatolhiman - Why do you think it would be better to use CSS Grid `grid-template-columns`?

Comment: I guess grid gives you more granular control over each element with a single line of css and better flow when you want boxes to break on to the next row etc. But flex-wrap and percentage widths that change for each media query breakpoint will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to remove max-width: 24%

```css
#parent {
  display: flex !important;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100% !important;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}
.item{
 flex: 1 !important;
 flex-basis: calc(100% / 4);
 box-sizing: border-box ;
 border: solid 1px #000000;
 margin-bottom: 30px !important;
  height: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
/* start of medium tablet styles */
 .item{
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3) !important;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
 .item{
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 2) !important;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You got it wrong mate. I assumed you needed the max-width to make it not fully wide if the item is only 1.

Remove the `max-width` and the `flex:1` and you should be good.

The `flex: 1` is redundant of `flex-basis: calc(100% / 4);`.

The `flex: 1` will make the item fully wide 100% while your telling it to divide the items into 4 groups/3 groups/2 groups using the `flex-basis: calc(100% / 4);`, so the `max-width` and `flex: 1` is doesn't make any sense anymore.

```css
#parent {
 display: flex !important;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 width: 100% !important;
 justify-content: flex-start;
}
.item{
 flex-basis: calc(100% / 4);
 box-sizing: border-box ;
 border: solid 1px #000000;
 margin-bottom: 30px !important;
 height: 50px;
}

/* For tablet */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .item{
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3) !important;
 }
}

/* For mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
 .item{
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 2) !important;
 }
}
```